# MySQLi : How to sort to make a ladder

Tags: php

I'm setting up a website based on server voting's. I would like to sort servers votes with mysqli and give them a rank, per example:

1: 88 votes Server1

2: 54 votes Server2

3:34 votes Server3...

I already have my servers and votes in my database, but I can't find the solution to sort them and to give them a rank.
It is like:

```
{rank} : {number of server's vote} {server name}
```

I already tried this:

```
    $totalserv = $database->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `servers` ");

    $votes = $database->query("SELECT `votes` FROM `servers` ORDER BY votes ASC");
```

But I don't understand how to make `$vote` a list and attribute it a rank.

Comment: What does `$votes` contain instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, change `DESC` and `ASC` accordingly

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` ORDER BY LEFT(`votes`,2) DESC;
```

Your query

```
$votes = $database->query("SELECT `votes` FROM `servers` ORDER BY LEFT(`votes`,2) ASC");
```

Comment: Thanks ! But how could i echo this now ?

Comment: @Léo you can execute it in phpmyadmin to see the expected result.